# How to stop or shutdown GeoServer on a Windows 10

Tags: geoserver, windows, jetty

How can I stop the GeoServer running on my Windows 10 computer? I downloaded geoserver-2.19.2-bin(zipped) Platform Independent Binary and extracted it into a folder I wanted (my Download folder). I have the Java environment set `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301` and also set the `GOESERVER_HOME` set to the location where the GeoServer application was extracted in my case `C:\Users\YO\Downloads\geoserver-2.19.2-bin`. When I try to shutdown I get the following error

```
Shutting down GeoServer...

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:570)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:546)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.doStop(Main.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:424)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I cannot stop the application and I can not delete the folder. Any ideas of how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Reinstall using the war option with Tomcat rather than Jetty, running as a windows service

Comment: ok, I thought that I might use that option later. I want to delete the folder but I cant because it says folder in use as the application is still running. I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: I have had this issue for long i guess you inspired me to solve it @nmtoken.

Comment: just close the window that jetty is running in

Comment: For some reason there was no jetty window or a geoserver terminal window. But its sorted now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a while to figure this out, though through @nmtoken's comment. In order to stop the running GeoServer, I checked all the open ports on my Windows 10 using the following command `netstat -aon` in the CMD shell. I was able to identify the the GeoServer process based on the port number it was running on

```
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       37776
```

For some reason when I check through the task manager or running processes it is not listed. So to stop the process I used the following command   `Stop-Process -ID 37776 -Force`  from Window Powershell (when I tried it from normal CMD terminal its says `'Stop-Process' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` ),  (I found this method from [Tutorial: PowerShell Kill Process Command](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/powershell-kill-process-command-tutorial/)). I was able to stop and then restart the GeoServer.